# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}$ at $z=2k\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need to find residue of function $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-\cos(z)}$ at $z=2\pi k$, where $k\in \Bbb Z$.
I know residue at $z=0$ from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168355/residue-of-fz-fracz1-cosz-at-z-0).
I got a hint that need to substitute $z=\hat z+2\pi k$, so $\hat z=z-2\pi k$, so I have to find residue at $\hat z=0$. So $f(\hat z)=\frac{\hat z+2\pi k}{1-\cos(\hat z)}$.
One more hint - I have to split function in two parts, when k is odd and k is even.

Answer (score 2):

no it has pole of order $2$ for $2k\pi$.see image.

[image]

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As the denominator 1-cosz has a simple pole at z=2kπ,
        Res(f;2kπ)= lim┬(z→2kπ)⁡〖z/(d/dz(1-cosz))〗