# Find residue of $\cos(\frac{z}{1-z})$ at z=1.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Is the residue of $\cos(\frac{z}{1-z})$ at z=1 : sin(1)?

i.e $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_c\cos(\frac{z}{1-z})dz=Res(\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z}),0)$=$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_c\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{z-1})}{z^2}dz$

Just wanted to clarify the method.

**Edit**

Using the following theorem:
[image]

Comment: Isolated essential singularity. Try Expanding the function about 1. Or Substitute $z-1=w$ and expand about zero. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168355/residue-of-fz-fracz1-cosz-at-z-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac z{1-z}\right)&=\cos\left(-1-\frac1{1-z}\right)\\&=\cos\left(1-\frac1{z-1}\right)\\&=\cos(1)\cos\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)+\sin(1)\sin\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)\\&=\cos(1)\left(1-\frac1{2!}\frac1{(z-1)^2}+\cdots\right)+\sin(1)\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{3!}\frac1{(z-1)^3}+\cdots\right)\end{align}and therefore the residue is $\sin(1)$, since that's the coefficient of $\frac1{z-1}$.

Comment: Thanks but if i use cauchy integral as above the solution is valid right?

Comment: @JhonDoe I don't know, since I don't know where the expression $\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)\right)$ comes from.

Comment: Oh sry. I was using the theorem above. See edit.

Comment: @JhonDoe Then what you did is fine.